# How does Gibbs get his boats out of his basement?

Tags: continuity, ncis

In most episodes, Gibbs in seen working on his boats in the basement. He gets a couple of them done, but it doesn't show how he gets them out of the basement.

Anybody know how he gets them out?

Comment: you refer to the boats it can be assumed he wouldn't want to burn. In one episode he mentioned that he builds and then destroys them and starts over (I have seen people positing that it is a catharsis to get over the failed marriages). So the boat he names Kelly he might not want to destroy.

Comment: Maybe he gets it through a trapdoor or hatch, e.g. for delivering coals.

Comment: hes Gibbs. we may never know how he does half of what he does. How does he always know what's going on in the squadroom? i think hes magic lol

Comment: One of his boats is seized by coast gaurd, towed to shore, dissassembled by Abby in her other lab.

Comment: He probably has a TARDIS hidden somewhere!

Comment: There is a hatch door in the roof similar to the one in the jumper bay in Atlantis...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has never been enough detail provided in the episodes that have aired to date - there are a few hints and a few jokes along the way (like knocking down a wall and using a ramp) - but this one doesn't really have an answer currently.

The boat "Diane" does have an *answer* as to what happened to it;

> In the episode "Kill Ari" (3x02) Jen goes home with Gibbs so he can change clothes after being out in the rain storm, and sees the boat Diane. She asks if this was the same boat he was building 6 years ago to which Gibbs answers no.
>
> When Jen asks what happened to the other one, Gibbs tells her that he burned the boat.

However, whether the boat was burned inside the house or not (unlikely, considering that burning a boat in a basement would probably burn the house down) is never covered in the show.

Comment: In another episode, he tells Ducky that he disassembled the previous boat and reassembled it in his garage. It seems the boat in the basement is somewhat of a running joke.

Comment: I supposed he could chop it up before burning it to avoid a house fire. Now *that* would be cathartic!

Comment: Doesn't he tell Tony in an episode that you just have to break the bottle?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer mentions conversation "like knocking down a wall and using a ramp."  This dialog comes from season 3 episode 7 - Honor Code when Gibbs is taking care of Zach while his father is missing:

> ZACH: Gibbs, can I ask you a question?
>
> GIBBS: Yeah, shoot.
>
> ZACH: How are you going to get this out of here when it’s finished?
>
> GIBBS: Good question.  I don’t know.  I haven’t thought about it much.
>
> ZACH: I think maybe you could use a crane or something.
>
> GIBBS: Yeah?  I could dig a ramp.  Knock that wall out and hoist it
>   out of here.
>
> ZACH: I went sailing once with my dad and Commander Wilder.  Didn’t go
>   too well.

This is one of the few pieces of dialog in the series which discusses getting the boat out of the basement (I am watching the series from the beginning, so there may be other hints in future episodes).  But it is unknown if Gibbs acted on this idea.